# Legal Statute Sorting Algorithm (Algorithmic Challenge)

Tags: node.js, algorithm, sorting

I have designed a down and dirty sorting algorithm for New Jersey Legal Statutes, but I'm looking for a better way. Statutes are formatted in the following manner:

- Title - A number < 999 and may include up to 2 letters after the title. Ex. 26, 26A, 26AA
- Chapter - Formatted exactly the same as title.
- Paragraph - A number < 999 which may be followed by 1-2 letters, and or a decimal point, and or a number < 999, and or a letter, and or another number. Ex. 25, 25.26, 25a, 25a.26, 25a.26b, 25aa.26, etc.

I convert the title and paragraph to decimals by stripping out the whole number in the beginning and dividing by 1000, giving me a decimal value which is converted to a string. I have assigned all letters(converted to lowercase) string values from 01-26. I add those values to the end of the initial whole number string sequentially. Any numbers also mixed in are added as their string value.

The obvious bottleneck is the mess of possibilities in the paragraph section. I have actually split that up to paragraph (pre any decimal) and section. I apply the above logic to the broken down sections if they exist.

As for the sorting 17 < 17A < 17AA < 17B < 18.

An example value conversion of `17B:26bb-2a5.1a5` would break down as the following:

- Title- `.01702`
- Chapter- `.0260202`
- Paragraph- `.002015`
- Section- `.001015`

Some more examples of statutes:

```
17:2-3
18B:2a-1
19AA:3-56g
26:56a-16
1:56-12.123
2:34–15.12a
```

The method I've devised is pretty dirty. I had to split it up in sections to ensure I had the correct values for each 'section' converting the whole number part to a decimal. I'm also using JS(Node) which doesn't handle large numbers well.

If anyone has a more efficient/clean way, any thoughts, or feedback, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: For title and chapter, it seems like all you need to is count the number of digits, and insert 0's at the beginning so that there are always three digits. Then ordinary string sorting will do the job.

Comment: You did not elaborate on the separators. Is it always a colon? Or when is it point. In the break down you mention a point at the start of every part, but that is not in the examples. Can you make this consistent and expand on the separators that are used?

Comment: Always colon then hyphen. I updated the examples.